# How to pass a prop with generics in Svelte

Tags: typescript, generics, svelte, sveltekit

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { enhance } from '$app/forms';
    import type { SubmitFunction } from '@sveltejs/kit';

    export let action: string;
    export let onSubmit: SubmitFunction<T>;
</script>

<form method="POST" {action} use:enhance={onSubmit}>
  <slot />
</form>
```

I'm trying to create a custom `FORM` component that will do several things for me in the future.  How do I get the `onSubmit` button to use a generic so that I can reuse it in different cases?

Right now I just get a `Cannot find name 'T'` error.

I tried something like this to no avail:

```
<script lang="ts" generics="T">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seemed to have got it working with this:

```
type T = $$Generic<Record<string, unknown> | undefined>;
```

I could not get it to work with the same generic using:

```html
<script lang="ts" generics="T extends Record<string, unknown> | undefined">
```

Not sure why, but I guess the old method works.